# Using large set of strings in word tree visualization

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I can't copy and paste all the strings in my file and run the code using this example

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

I modified the html and javascript code and replaced phrases with a small set of strings from my file and got everything to work. Now I want to do the same thing with my full file, but there are too many strings to copy and paste. How can I use javascript to import my large dataset and do I make each row formatted the same with "['some text here']," or does javascript insert the brackets when the file is uploaded?

The HTML File:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:['wordtree']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
          [ ['Phrases'],
                    ['return refund not received'],
                        ['hello, every time i try to print the invoice, nothing loads. i have tried different browsers and devices. can i get it emailed to me?'],
                        ['how long for delivery and do i need a prescription'],
                        ['i recently requested replacement lenses for some that were defective and received the wrong prescription'],
                        ['my order is pending verification of prescription.  however, my prescription hasn’t changed and i ordered last month without any delays.'],

          ]
        );

        var options = {
          wordtree: {
            format: 'implicit',
            //alt is 'suffix', 'prefix'
            type: 'double',
            word: 'prescription'
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('wordtree_basic'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wordtree_basic" style="width: 1800px; height: 1000px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript File:

```
 google.charts.load('current', {packages:['wordtree']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
          [ ['Phrases'],
                    ['return refund not received'],
                        ['hello, every time i try to print the invoice, nothing loads. i have tried different browsers and devices. can i get it emailed to me?'],
                        ['how long for delivery and do i need a prescription'],
                        ['i recently requested replacement lenses for some that were defective and received the wrong prescription'],
                        ['my order is pending verification of prescription.  however, my prescription hasn’t changed and i ordered last month without any delays.'],
          ]
        );

        var options = {
          wordtree: {
            format: 'implicit',
            //alt is 'suffix', 'prefix'
            type: 'double',
            word: 'prescription'
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('wordtree_basic'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

I would like to be able to upload the file (csv format) from my desktop (or other location) instead of copying and pasting small sections of my open ended feedback. Thanks.

Comment: did you check a `fetch api` for JS? That can be helpful for you. Other options are to paste content of the file into for example `div` or `textarea` on the page and in JS read it value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Google sheet.

#### Snippet:

```
function drawVisualization() {
        var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'WordTree',
          dataSourceUrl: 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7V',
          query: 'SELECT A',
          containerId: 'wordtree_basic'
        });
}
```

#### To Read:

- [Google sheets Integration](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#introduction)
- [ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts#chartwrapper)
- [Csv import](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+Import+csv)

Comment: Let me give the google sheets a try and I'll let you know how that works.

Comment: Thanks TheMaster for the documentation. I got it working with Google Sheets with a smaller sample. Now I'm going to try and add in the larger sample of responses.

Comment: It looks like the wordtree might just have issues with larger datasets. I put a few 100 in and it worked fine, but when I tried adding 25K it keeps crashing.

Comment: @gsheppard Is there a specific error on the console? To ask, what exactly are you trying to show with 25k lines? I don't think you'll get anything reasonable.

Comment: I'm using Fiddle meta to run the code, and I'm not seeing an error, just the image showing a sad face that it didn't run. We're pulling specific comments from customers about different experiences, so we're trying to bring in as many customers' responses as possible to see what main themes come out of the analysis.

Comment: I was able to get it to work for a second with about 13K before crashing, so I think probably will just have to keep shrinking the dataset down till I get something that is manageable both for the code to run and for analysis.

Comment: @gshepp May be fiddle is the problem? Try in a real site or local browser?